# Intercept USB-keyboard data before Windows registers it as keystroke

Tags: c#, windows, usb

I've been searching the Web for a quite specific problem.. What I'm trying to do is to have two keyboards (normal USB qwerty ones) connected to my PC on two different USB-ports, from which I can choose which one is 'active' and is used to write with, whilst the other keyboard will be used for different commands in my application and not being able to write with.

Basically intercept/disconnect the part where Windows reads the input-data and treats it as a keystroke on a specific USB-port, and instead gives me the data for usage.

Are there any way of doing this preferably in C#?

Comment: This definitely can not be done on the C# level, if it is possible at all it would be as a custom driver which would need to be written in a native language.

Comment: That or you need to use low level hooks. Sounds definitely hard, but if anti-keyloggers could do it, theoretically, so could you. Possibly almost impossible, but somewhat doable to a certain extent.

Answer (score 1):

There is an article about using RawInput in C# to detect where keystrokes originate from when you have multiple keyboards attached. This could help you provision one keyboard for normal use for typing and another for specialized use in your C# app.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard